# Not able to upload Image in Form Data from React Native to Next JS API backend(code included)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, next.js13

React Native Code:

```
const formData = new FormData()
    
    formData.append('image', blob, filename)
     // Where Blob is taken from Expo library from taking photos from camera
    
     try {
        const response = await axios.post<Avatar>(
          `${BASE_URL}/api/user/avatar`,
          formData,
          config,
        )
        return response.data
      } catch (error) {
        if (axios.isAxiosError(error)) {
          const axiosError = error as AxiosError
          if (axiosError.response?.status === 400) {
            // Handle the specific case where the status code is 400
            throw new Error('Missing required data (userId or avatarData)')
          } else {
            // Handle other Axios errors or status codes as needed
            throw error
          }
        } else {
          // Handle other generic errors
          throw error
        }
      }
```

Next JS backend:

```
    export async function POST(request: Request) {
  try {
    const formData = await request.formData();

    const file = formData.get("image");
```

What i'm seeing that file comes empty. However, when i post form-data via Postman i can see that the file comes through. Any suggestions on what I could try?

If i log FormData on the FrontEnd it looks like this:

```
{"_parts":[["image",{"_data":{"size":6394480,"offset":0,"blobId":"588C85C0-BCD8-46DF-91A9-2AA1EE7BADA7","type":"image/jpeg","name":"EE1D1CE3-C07D-4B95-8027-4BA58923DFCE.jpg","__collector":{}}}],["userId","8"]]}
```